# Getting CloudFront to Work with EC2 Wordpress Installation + Route 53

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem getting CloudFront to work with a BitNami Wordpress installation I’ve done on an EC2 instance.

This is my first time working with EC2, so please forgive my noob level in AWS knowledge.

I created an EC2 instance and installed Wordpress by BitNami via the marketplace. I kept all the basic settings. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEutT.png)

I allocated a new elastic IP and associated it with the instance. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVg8T.png)

This is the public DNS (IPv4): ec2-35-169-133-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com

The weird thing is, when you visit the URL it only shows the following IP address in the browsers’ address bar: http://35.169.133.115

In all the tutorial videos I've watched, this doesn't happen. It only seems to happen to me. Does anyone know why and how to disable this?

Next I created a new CloudFront distribution with ‘ec2-35-169-133-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com’ as my origin and entered my domain name ’voucherchampion.com’ as Alternate Domain Name (CNAMEs). [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrZqx.png)

I set up a new Route 53 hosted zone and created a ‘A’ record set with my CloudFront URL as the alias target (dx9tz3fhvx56h.cloudfront.net.). [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08GzA.png)

I changed the DNS settings in my NameCheap dashboard (where I bought the domain name) to match the route 53 name server values. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oFhb.png)

Now where I visit voucherchampion.com, it goes to my Wordpress installation, but:

1) Shows the elastic IP in the address bar instead of the domain name

2) Doesn’t use CloudFront.

I suspect it has something to do with:

‘ec2-35-169-133-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com’ redirecting to ’35.169.133.115’.

Does anyone know how I can get CloudFront to work and how to show my domain name in the address bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick ideas that might help, but probably not a full solution 1) In the Wordpress admin area change the site URL from the IP address to the domain name 2) Use an Alias record in Route53, not an A record.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your reply. I can't change the site URL from to IP address to the domain name in the settings tab, the fields are both locked for some reason... Also, I think I already created an Alias record in Route53, the Alias checkbox is marked 'yes'. You can check it in the screenshot I attached.

Comment: You need to login as a Wordpress admin to change that. If you can't change it figure out that problem first, then get back to the bigger picture.